# How to build a dynamic calendar in MVC 3 ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, calendar

I'm developing a MVC 3 online application of tennis clubs management...

I would like to add a dynamic calendar to make a reservation as a customer more "easier"...

Here an [example](http://www.boisdelacambre.be/tableau.php5) (in french)

So, the calendar would have a Schedule (changing follow the tennis club of the user who is connected) and all the tennis courts...

***I'm a beginner in MVC 3, so my question is:***

How to build this calendar ? What tools I need to use ? JQuery, WebGrid ?

Of course, I'm not requesting that you make my work but just some advise and examples if it's possible...Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at this open source project - http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ It is a jQuery based calendar widget that looks similar to what you need and is very flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery UI datepicker control.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

There is an onSelect event, where you can show another div where user can enter the registration info.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
     //Show the div here
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you response ! But I have already more datepicker in my project :D So I would like to make something new and more "appeal"...

Comment: @Francesco : You can always customize the Calender CSS to make it looks more appealing.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. And yes, you'd be using jquery with jquery UI (which contains a datapicker widget) and other plugins for the client side and asp.net mvc for the server part.

However, I strongly recommend to spend a little time to understand what is asp.net mvc, the difference between client side and server side and to practice with simpler applications.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advise I will spend more time to understand MVC